# Javascript Spark AR On each touch rotate object 90 degrees smoothly

Tags: javascript, facebook, instagram, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I would like to rotate a 3d object smoothly 90 degrees on each touch by script, reaching 360 on the 4th touch and resetting. I tried this in Patches and i couldn't achieve it. So far i have this code below, it works first touch 90 degrees but remains stationary on each touch after. The loop variable increase a quarter on each touch. I thought this would work in theory, but it doesn't. The task seems simple, but just cant get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. I'm new to JS & Spark btw. Many Thanks.

```
const Scene = require('Scene');const Reactive = require('Reactive');const TouchGestures = require('TouchGestures');const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

var i = 0; var taps = 1; var loops = .25;

(async function () {


const myobject = await Scene.root.findFirst('BOX');
    const Animation = require('Animation');
    const timeDriver = Animation.timeDriver({
    durationMilliseconds: 5000,
    loopCount: loops,
    mirror: false
});

TouchGestures.onTap().subscribe(function (gesture) {
    i++;
    if (i == taps) {
        i = 0;
        QuarterTurn();
        loops = loops + .25;
    }
})

//Need object to rotate 90 degrees smoothly on each new Touch, 4x Touches = 360 degrees.
function QuarterTurn() {

    
    const sampler = Animation.samplers.linear(0, 2 * Math.PI);
    myobject.transform.rotationX = Animation.animate(timeDriver, sampler);
    timeDriver.start();
    Diagnostics.log(loops);
    Diagnostics.log(taps);
}
})();
```

Getting Close it works on first touch reaches 90 degrees, but that's where it ends. Wont turn an additional 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

0.25 loops is the issue here

You need to count current tap and then calculate start and end angles, also I've added some housekeeping to the script.

```js
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Reactive = require('Reactive');
const TouchGestures = require('TouchGestures');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');


(async function () {

  const myobject = await Scene.root.findFirst('BOX');
  const Animation = require('Animation');
  const timeDriver = Animation.timeDriver({
    durationMilliseconds: 5000,
    loopCount: 1,
    mirror: false
  });

  const PI_2 = Math.PI * 0.5;
  let i = 0;

  TouchGestures.onTap().subscribeWithSnapshot(
    {
      isRunning: timeDriver.isRunning()
    },
    function (gesture, snapshot) {
      // adding lock on tap to finish current animation loop
      if (!snapshot.isRunning) {
        QuarterTurn();
        Diagnostics.log("Current tap : " + i);
        i++;
      } else {
        Diagnostics.log("Animation is running!!!");
      }
    });

  function QuarterTurn() {
    const start = i * PI_2;
    const end = start + PI_2;
    const sampler = Animation.samplers.linear(start, end);
    myobject.transform.rotationX = Animation.animate(timeDriver, sampler);
    timeDriver.reset();
    timeDriver.start();
  }

})();
```